# vscode+ESP-IDF How to light up the oled screen

Tags: esp32

I am new to esp32 programming.I wanted to try to light up the screen,but i don't know how to download the relevant library on vscode or IDF.Thanks for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1OSA.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60qfr.png)
I think the reason is I don't downdoad the relevant library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*Sidenote: The solution is the first result on a Google search of your error. It might be prudent to try doing a search before opening a question.*

Based on your question, I've assumed that you're using PlatformIO with ESP-IDF, in VSCode.

From the compilation logs, it appears that the `Wire` library is missing. To resolve that, you can simply add `lib_deps = Wire` under the `[env]` section  of your `platformio.ini` file. So, the `[env]` section of the `platformio.ini` file should look like this:

```
[env]
platform = https://github.com/tasmota/platform-espressif32/#Tasmota/204
board = nodemcu-32s
framework = arduino, espidf
upload_port = /dev/cu.usbserial-0001
monitor_port = /dev/cu.usbserial-0001
monitor_speed = 115200
lib_deps = Wire ; <--- This line
```